# how to tell the users, that application has removed from the server?

Tags: tomcat

Hi i have removed one application from my tomcat server. now i need to tell the users, that application got removed from the path. Use new URL(it will be in new server).

if any user hits the new URL, he need to be notified with a message saying application got removed.

how to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than removing the old application, you can put a redirect page to redirect users to the new URL.

Comment: old server is not in my control, new application is in my server. so if any user hits old url, i need to show the message.